# What is correct way to stop query indexing using Robots.txt?

Tags: wordpress, googlebot, web-crawlers, robots.txt

How to stop indexing search result using Robots.txt?

hello.

Recently, I'm having an issue with indexed pages in Google Search Console growing 10x.

These pages are mostly search query (/?s=) and consist of spam queries that have nothing to do with my website, such as Casino and Porn.

What I don't understand is that I've been using robots.txt like this about 5 years ago.

```
Sitemap: https://example.com/sitemap_index.xml
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Disallow: *?orderby=*
Disallow: /?cat=usd&order=desc
Disallow: *?cat=usd&order=desc
Disallow: /?s=
Disallow: /search/
Disallow: /*/page/*
Disallow: */page/*
Disallow: /?s
Disallow: */uncategorized/
Disallow: */?s
Disallow: *?s=
Disallow: /test/*
Disallow: /test2/*
Disallow: /test3/*
Disallow: /test4/*
Disallow: /test5/*
Disallow: /test/
Disallow: /test2/
Disallow: /test3/
Disallow: /test4/
Disallow: /test5/
```

Nevertheless, the search results were indexed by Google.

Could someone please let me know if there is a problem with the Robots.txt I use?

Comment: It is likely that your site was hacked. The hackers may be surreptitiously using a different robots.txt file for Googlebot. Have you cleaned up the hack?  Have you tested the indexed URLs against [Google's robots.txt Tester](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062598?hl=en)?

Comment: Is it possible that the page with such a param returns a different **canonical url** to one without a param ?

Comment: To add to the previous two good suggestions, how do you check that your search results are being indexed? It is usually pretty hard to make google index search results. And what does your site show for those search results? I typically make my enterprise clients serve a custom 404 page when nothing is found for a query exactly for this reason.

Comment: Hi, @StephenOstermiller  Thanks for answering. I also suspected malware firstly and checked my DB and whole website but there was no problem. Checking Robots.txt is also fine.

Comment: Have you checked them through Google's tools?  Some malware implements cloaking so it only appears for Googlebot and searchers coming from Google.

Comment: Hi, @RohitGupta Thanks for answering. no. its not possible. Spam queris redirected to a 404 page automatically because my website doesn't have a pages or posts related to spam queries (Casino). There is no page to specify canonical in the query string.

Comment: Hi, @StephenOstermiller Yes. I checked through Google Search Console as you pointed out. And I posted this problem to Google Search Forum.

They answered to me "blocking Google bots with robots.txt and indexing them are two different things". 

I am little confused. What I've known so far is that blocking bots makes it impossible to index. But Google says indexing and crawling are separate things.

Comment: They are separate things. See [Search engines that index your site despite a disallow in robots.txt](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/56189/search-engines-that-index-your-site-despite-a-disallow-in-robots-txt/56190#56190)

Comment: Where does Google Search Console report it is finding links to these spam search results?

Comment: H, @BNazaruk Thanks for answering. I agree with you. I've never seen search query indexed before. And since there are no search results on my website that match the spam query, automatically redirected to a 404 page.
However, Google Search Console indexed thousands of spam search terms. Screenshot ```https://imgsh.net/a/UG3eqH4.jpg```

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Sure. You can check it out in the screenshot.```https://imgsh.net/a/4iQYWsx.jpg``` Although written in Korean, all these are spam queries.

Comment: That screenshot doesn't show what other sites link to those spam search results.

Comment: I still think your site is hacked, or had been hacked at some point. Its possible that Google is just indexing search results based on external links.  But with thousands of URLs, it seems way more likely to be a problem with your site itself.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller okay. Thanks for your advice. Could you please let me know if Hacked, How do i find it and what should I do? When i checked my website using  malware and hack scanners from Wordpress, there is no problem.

Comment: Have you used Google Search Console's URL inspection tool with your pages in a live test?  That is usually a good way to detect a hack.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Now I checked with one of the URLs. Screenshot ```https://imgsh.net/a/SsWL50Q.jpg``` I have deleted all urls starting with /?s= through Google Search Console.
But strange site was displayed in the reference link, and when I entered, it linked to the some forum of a website. and had a posted similar posts to the one indexed on my site.

Comment: That would be typical of a hack.  Many sites get hacked and the hackers link them together to fool Google's PageRank algorithms.

Comment: Yes, I second Stephen's idea. This does look like a classical case of a doorway. Still popular in Korea, apparently. Well, as long as it works, I guess. To test it, either change your user agent to Googlebot and visit the pages, or temporarily allow indexing and fetch as google through GSC. You should see the doorway in action that way. You should also be able to fins a shell on your FTP if the hackers were sloppy and didn't touch it to change the creation date. And you should see the garbage pages in your DB.

Comment: You are experiencing what is referred to as Search Spam. Not only that, but you are also exposing yourself to a PII penalty from Google. A couple of things to do (apart from Robots.txt). 1) Your search pages should return a no-index meta to avoid this risk. 2) Several plugins can scan for malware to determine if you have a hack (Sucuri, Bulletproof security, etc.).